# How do I fix this kind of error in NodeJS?

Tags: node.js

How do I fix this error?

```
C:\Users\admin>npm install -g n
npm ERR! code EBADPLATFORM
npm ERR! notsup Unsupported platform for n@9.2.0: wanted {"os":"!win32"} (current: {"os":"win32"})
npm ERR! notsup Valid os:  !win32
npm ERR! notsup Actual os: win32

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2024-01-02T05_17_35_713Z-debug-0.log
```

I'm trying to update my NodeJS version but this error pops up.

Comment: Reading the [docs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/n)  "*n does not work in native shells on Microsoft Windows (like PowerShell), or Git for Windows BASH, or with the Cygwin DLL.*"  From the cited error it seems you are trying to install `n` from the windows CMD or Powershell, which is not supported

Comment: what im going to do?

Comment: If you want to keep using Windows but run your development environment to use this package, you can explore using WSL in Windows for development. This way you'll be able to install the package since the environment will be in Linux.

Comment: Or better yet, you can use nvm instead of n. @RalphEfrenEco